# Call function from another function NameError: name 'MethodName' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I am new in python. How can call function from another function. Here is an example :

```
class TSMTViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Tsmt.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TsmtSerializer

def RunNew2N3(fromempid,toempid,fromdate,todate,fromcscid='',tocscid=''):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.callproc('[dbo].[SPRUN]',[fromempid,toempid,fromdate,todate,fromcscid,tocscid])        
    finally:
        cursor.close()

def create(self,request):
    tsmt  = request.data.get('tsmt')

    tsmt['createby']="Admin"             
    tsmt['createdate']=datetime.datetime.now()    

    fromempid = tsmt['empid']
    toempid = tsmt['empid']
    fromdate = tsmt['tdate']
    todate = tsmt['tdate']




    serializer = TsmtSerializer(data=tsmt)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        tsmt_saved = serializer.save()

        RunNew2N3(fromempid,toempid,fromdate,todate)

        return Response({"result":"TSMT '{}' created successfully".format(tsmt_saved.tdate),"status":"success"})
    else:
        return Response({"result":"'{}'".format(serializer.errors),"status":"fail"})
```

I put the call function on top and why I can't call that.I got the error message

> NameError: name 'RunNew2N3' is not defined

Comment: Are these methods or functions? Are they in a class? `create` takes a `self` argument but `RunNew2N3` does not. Please show the full code and how you're calling it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman , Please see the update.

Comment: That hasn't really helped. Is the indentation correct? Are `RunNew2N3` and `create` inside TSMTViewSet? If not, why does `create` take `self`? If so, please fix the indentation and explain why `RunNew2N3` does *not* take `self`.

Comment: Indentation is correct and both functions are inside the views. I know indenting in question is incorrect but I don't know how to use the tag in here. create take self because of this is request method and I don't know whether should I put also self in RunNew2N3 function. I am a new dude.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an indentation issue, if `RunNew2N3` isn't part of `TSMTViewSet`, define it outside and also align `create` inside the class:

```
def RunNew2N3(fromempid,toempid,fromdate,todate,fromcscid='',tocscid=''):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.callproc('[dbo].[SPRUN]',[fromempid,toempid,fromdate,todate,fromcscid,tocscid])        
    finally:
        cursor.close()

class TSMTViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Tsmt.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TsmtSerializer

    def create(self,request):
        tsmt  = request.data.get('tsmt')

        tsmt['createby']="Admin"             
        tsmt['createdate']=datetime.datetime.now()    

        fromempid = tsmt['empid']
        toempid = tsmt['empid']
        fromdate = tsmt['tdate']
        todate = tsmt['tdate']

        serializer = TsmtSerializer(data=tsmt)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            tsmt_saved = serializer.save()

            RunNew2N3(fromempid,toempid,fromdate,todate)

            return Response({"result":"TSMT '{}' created successfully".format(tsmt_saved.tdate),"status":"success"})
        else:
            return Response({"result":"'{}'".format(serializer.errors),"status":"fail"})
```

Comment: Indentation is exactly same with u , Sry I try to do in question and I can't use tab in question. If Runnew2n3 is part of create, how to write this code?

Answer (score 0):

This is basic Python. If a function is a method on a class instance, it needs to:

- be indented within the class
- accept `self` as the first parameter
- be called via `self`.

So:

```
class TSMTViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...

    def RunNew2N3(self, fromempid, toempid, fromdate, todate, fromcscid='', tocscid=''):
        ...

    def create(self, request):
        ...
        self.RunNew2N3(fromempid, toempid, fromdate, todate)
        ...
```